# Download all files from all sub-directories from Azure data lake Gen2 path using python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to download all the files from all the folders listed inside the source folder from AZURE ADLS Gen2 space. The path looks like below

```
abfss://abc@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/rock/final_update/ROCK_OrdersDetails
```

There are multiple folders inside ROCK_OrdersDetails, I need to visit each folder and download all files inside it to my local.
I am using python for the same, I tried some approaches but they didn't work. I am using below versions

```
azure-storage-file-datalake 12.10.0
python 3.10
```

As of now I am able to download all the files inside a single folder, below is the code. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import FileSystemClient, DataLakeServiceClient

    def download_to_local(
        credential: ClientSecretCredential,
        storage_account_name: str,
        file_system_name: str,
        directory_name: str,
        destination_path: str,
    ):
        from pathlib import Path
        Path(destination_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
            account_url=f"https://{file_system_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/",
            credential=credential,
        )
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=file_system_name)
        paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path=directory_name)
        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(directory_name)
        try:
            for path in paths:
                path_name: str = path.name.split("/")[-1]
                file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(path_name)
                local_file_path = os.path.join(destination_path, path_name)
                download = file_client.download_file()
                downloaded_bytes = download.readall()
                with open(local_file_path, 'wb') as local_file:
                    local_file.write(downloaded_bytes)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(e)



storage_account_name: xyz
file_system_name: abc
directory_name: rock/final_update/ROCK_OrdersDetails
destination_path: /tmp/rock/final_update/ROCK_OrdersDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.
I have used connection string and downloaded the file.

```
from  azure.storage.filedatalake  import  FileSystemClient, DataLakeServiceClient
import  os

connection_string  =  f"your connection string"

def  download_files_from_directory(file_system_client, directory_name,destination_path):

    paths  =  file_system_client.get_paths(path=directory_name)
    for  path  in  paths:
        if  path.is_directory:
            os.makedirs(destination_path+"/"+path.name, exist_ok=True)
        else:
            file_client  =  file_system_client.get_file_client(path.name)
            print(destination_path+"/"+path.name)
            
            with  open(destination_path+"/"+path.name, 'wb') as  local_file:
                file_client.download_file().readinto(local_file)

def  download_to_local(file_system_name: str,directory_name: str,destination_path: str):

    datalake_service_client  =  DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    file_system_client  =  datalake_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=file_system_name)
    directory_client  =  file_system_client.get_directory_client(directory_name)
    os.makedirs(destination_path, exist_ok=True)
    download_files_from_directory(file_system_client, directory_name,destination_path)

download_to_local(file_system_name="Your file system",directory_name="result",destination_path="FromAdls2")
```

Below are the data in storage account.

[image]

[image]

This are the files downloaded.

[image]

Output:

[image]